# Unsupported path error when creating namespace in HashiCorp

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When trying to create a namespace at path, it returns the following error.

```sh
$ vault namespace create ns1
Error creating namespace: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/namespaces/ns1
Code: 404. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
        * unsupported path
```

Creating new secret engines and putting new kv entries are working well.

Comment: I had the same problem with the open source / free version of Hashicorp Vault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked with the **Vault Enterprise** version.

The namespace support is only available with Vault Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the Vault Version, whereas creating Namespace and accessing Vault using namespace is done only when the Vault is Enterprise,
i.e Vault Enterprise, you can check here:

[Vault Enterprise Installation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/enterprise/hashicorp-enterprise-license)